# How to pay without saving card in Flutter using Stripe?

Tags: android, flutter, stripe-payments

We came across the paymentRequestWithCardFrom() method but this also has the saves the card UI.
We just want to pay via a new card and don't want to use this card for future use in a flutter project.

Comment: If you don't want to reuse the card later, skip saving it to a Customer object. A card that isn't attached to a Customer will be consumed when charged.

Comment: @taintedzodiac Might be a good idea to write that comment as an answer with some documentation supporting it.